# Cannot load KNNImputer even after updating sklearn to 0.23.2

Tags: python, scikit-learn, jupyter-notebook

When I tried to load `from sklearn.impute import KNNImputer` on Jupyter Notebook, it gave me the following error.

> ImportError: cannot import name 'KNNImputer' from 'sklearn.impute' (C:\Users\aura-\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\impute_*init*_.py)

I have updated sklearn to the newest version.

```
(base) C:\Users\aura->pip install -U scikit-learn
Requirement already up-to-date: scikit-learn in c:\users\aura-\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (0.23.2)
```

But when I checked on Jupyter Notebook again `import sklearn;print(sklearn.__version__)`, it is still showing `0.21.3`

Why the update is not reflected on Jupyter Notebook?

Comment: do have any other python directory?(not anaconda)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your package paths seem to be confused. The error you provide searches for the package in:

```
\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages
```

But the sci-kit learn you updated is in:

```
\anaconda3\lib\site-packages
```

When you install Anaconda, it creates the `anaconda3` folder. Did you create an `Anaconda3` folder?

Anyway, wherever you're running your Jupyter Notebook, Python is searching the undesired folder for the packages. Check this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3701646/how-to-add-to-the-pythonpath-in-windows-so-it-finds-my-modules-packages) on Stack Exchange for how to edit your PYTHONPATH. I would recommend removing the path to `Anaconda3`, and adding the path to `anaconda3` in your PYTHONPATH.

**Something else you can try, if you rather:**

Alternatively, use conda to create a virtual environment using `conda create` and `conda activate` to enter the environment. When in a virtual environment, if you run Jupyter then conda should direct Python to the correct path [i.e `\path\to\anaconda3`]. This is the primary function of conda.